# SVN: Why does trunk automatically update from my branch?

Tags: svn

I just created a branch of my svn repository.  I'm going to be working in the branch for another week or so, so I used the "switch" command to switch over to the branch.  Everything seemed to work fine, except now if I do an svn update on the trunk, it automatically merges the changes from the branch into the trunk!

How I prevent this from happening?  I have some stuff in the branch that is specific to that branch (configuration stuff) and I don't want that getting merged in automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `svn info` in the top level directory of your working directory to confirm that you really did `svn switch` to the right branch. It could be that you ran `svn switch` in a subdirectory, which would give you mixed branches... anything outside that subdirectory would still be in trunk, so `svn update` run in that directory would give you updates from trunk, not your branch.

Comment: I think you're right... if I get the entire folder structure out of source control, everything is fine.  So I think it's something with my local copy.

Answer (score 2):

I would double-check the command you used, and make sure that you actually switched your working copy. That's the only reason I can think of that would cause this behavior. SVN wouldn't automatically merge in changes otherwise.